# Append object into an array inside a object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

*NOTE: I'm open to other solutions. The objective of this code is to easily get all events on a particular day by accessing it with a date. This might not be the greatest solution.*

I want to push an "event" object into the correct array however I can't get it to work.

Below is the object that I want to "add" to.

```
this.state = {
    events: {
        Wed Apr 14 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time): [],
        Tue Apr 15 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time): [],
        and so on....
    }
}
```

The "date-key"'s time is always the same (00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)) however not the day, month, or year.

And here is my attempt to get this to work:

```
addEvent(event) {
        const events = this.state.events;
        const date = event.date;
        let list = [];

        if (typeof events[date] !== 'undefined') {
            list = events[date];
        }

        list.push(event);
        //console.log(events[date]);

        this.setState({
            events: {
                [date]: list
            }
        });
    }
```

(The event parameter that is passed in is an object with a "new Date()" attribute as event.date.)

Comment: Wed Apr 14 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time). The time is always the same (00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)) however not the day, month, or year. @maioman

Comment: You can have a variable name with space in between. So what you want to achieve in state is not possible with that name.

Comment: @Yadab I create the variable name by using `events: {
                [date]: list
            }` as you can see in the addEvent function where date is a "new Date()". I'm however open to other solutions.

Comment: Do you mean you want list of the events with the date? Or list of events for the particular date?

Comment: I want a list of events for the particular date. I.e. on Monday there are [Swim, Walk, Run] and on Tuesday there are [Jump, Eat] and so on.

Comment: So there can be only 7 keys inside `events` state. Am I right?

Comment: No, there can be an infinite amount because I need events for each day. I.e. Monday week 10, Monday week 11, and so on.

Comment: Not a solution to your question, but the assignment to `list` can be done much simpler as follows: `const list = events[date] || [];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. Based on the latest comment you have made.

```
addEvent(event) {
        const { events } = this.state;
        const date = event.date.getTime();
        let list = [];

        if (typeof events[date] !== 'undefined') {
            list = events[date];
        }

        list.push(event);
        //console.log(events[date]);

        this.setState((state) => ({
            events: {
                ...state.events,
                [date]: list,
            },
        }));
    }
```

Remember to create a date if your `event.date` is not type of Date.

```
addEvent(event) {
        const { events } = this.state;
        const date = new Date(event.date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maintain an array for days in a way you store them in events state lie

```
let days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
```

Now you can use the `date.getUTCDay()` or `date.getDay()` function depending on whether date in in `UTC` for or not to extract the day and then update it in your state

```
addEvent(event) {
    const events = this.state.events;
    const dayOfWeek = days[event.date.getUTCDay()];
    let list = [];

    if (typeof events[dayOfWeek ] !== 'undefined') {
        list = events[dayOfWeek];
    }

    list.push(event);
    this.setState({
        events: {
            ...this.state.events,
            [dayOfWeek]: list
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I might have phrased the question poorly the "day" key looks like this: "Wed Apr 14 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)" because I need separate events for each day. The time is always the same (00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)) however not the day, month, or year.

Comment: The logic should still work as long as date is a Date Object. If it is not, you can create a Date object using  `new Date(event.date)` and then use the above logic

Comment: Seems like this will work for you as per your requirement.

Comment: I might be a bit slow, but does this support an infinite amount of events? I need events for each day. I.e. Monday week 10, Monday week 11, and so on. Sorry if these are stupid questions, this is my first React project :)

Comment: Also `list.push(event);` this will mutate the original array. To be in safe side, you can use directly `[dayOfWeek]: list.concat(event)`.